# Updating and processing data in the background (at a specified interval)

Tags: android, background, notifications

The title migth already tell something about my problem. I simply describe what the App should do.

1. Download xml data in the background at a specified interval (not only when the UI is running)
2. Process this data
3. If the data says so -> send notification
4. If the user opens the UI, let the UI get the data
5. If the user closes the UI the interval should still be in place

Some people recommended services and some said one should use the Alarm System of Android, because ongoing Services take away to much memory and are likely to get killed by the system.

Can someone help me to find the best approach on this?

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of Alarm Manager:

1. The Alarm Manager holds CPU wake lock and ensures that `onReceive` method would be executed. Also it can wake up the device for doing the work.
2. As you say service can be destroyed by system and it holds resources.

So I think for this work you should use Alarm Manager, it is designed specially for doing work  at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sync adapter.
You can configure the sync adapter to run at a specified interval. The system will check to make sure that a network is available. The sync adapter runs in the background. It can send a notification.

The standard pattern for notifications is that if the user clicks the notification, it issues a content Intent. That Intent should go back to an Activity in your app. This pattern is described in the Notifications API guide and the Notifying the User training class.

When the user closes the UI, the interval will still be in place; it remains until you change it or remove the sync adapter.

See the class [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).

Post a comment if this approach doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure is it possible to start the SyncAdapter in a BroadcastReciever on Boot and still communicate with it on the Activity Level?